# $.ajax - Global Error Handling when Error Function Not Defined

Tags: ajax, jquery

For the jQuery `$.ajax` call:

I want to have a global error handler, something like this:

```
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        window.location = '/Error/ServerError';
    });
```

BUT ... I only want this to run when the `error`method on the `$.ajax` calls are not defined.  I see if they are not explicitly defined, they are anonymous methods, but I don't know how to check if a method is anonymous vs. named.

So, for something like this, I do NOT want the global handler called:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ShowError("Error", errorThrown);
    }
});
```

But for this call, I would like the global handler called, and the page redirected:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could check the `settings` parameter in the global handler whether or not there is an `error` field defined:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if ( settings.error )
        return;
    window.location = '/Error/ServerError';
});
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3xX6/)

Comment: It's working in the jsFiddle, but for some reason, it's not working in my project.  `settings.error` is always true whether it's defined or anonymous.

Comment: Which browser/jQuery version are you using? In Firefox/Chrome/Safari/IE6 with jQuery >= 1.5 `settings.error` is not anonymous, but `undefined`, so the method above works (I couldn't make the example work in Opera or jQuery <= 1.4). When you `console.log(settings)` does it **always** have `error` defined in your project? Are you calling `$.ajax` the same way you described in the question? (i.e. is there any chance some other code is injecting the error parameter when there is none?)